# C/C++, How do you code for the download progress thing in the CLI? Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, text, command-line-interface

Im looking to make program with a similar feature as the Download Progress Text with the arrow going across..
Example [PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6NUz.png) is a reference to what im talking about.

Any libraries or designs with basic functions?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: May be this is using a Bazooka to Kill a Mosquito but you can always use ncurses.

Comment: ...or just dig into a curses library code (there are several out there) to find out the way they implement character positioning and try to code it yourself...

Answer (score 1):

The library you are looking for is `ncurses`. It can be found [here](http://math.hws.edu/orr/s04/cpsc225/curses.html).

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cg_u60jX8Y4) is another resource I found for `ncurses` that may be useful to help introduce you to the library and its functionality. It's a series of Youtube tutorials -- his speaking is poor but from what I can tell (listening only to the first two videos) his examples are sufficiently well taught.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`boost::progress_display`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/timer/timer.htm#Class%20progress_display)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is a progress bar for some data, you should check out [`pv`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pv). One way to use it is to simply pipe your data through the program. Here is a simple example below that just reads in a file using a call to `pv` with `popen()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char pv[1024];
    FILE *infile;
    if (argc > 1) {
        char c;
        snprintf(pv, sizeof(pv), "pv %s", argv[1]);
        infile = popen(pv, "r");
        while (fread(&c, 1, 1, infile)) {}
        pclose(infile);
    } else {
        puts("need a file name!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```